# The type or namespace name 'Xaml' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows.UI'

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, namespaces, windows-phone-8.1, progress-bar

I created my project for windows phone 8 then i converted my project to windows phone 8.1.Now i need to use Progressbar ring into my project, but it showing error

> The type or namespace name 'Xaml' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Windows.UI'

How can i resolve this issues form my app

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It maybe because your project was updated to Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight and ProgressRing supports only WinRT.

Comment: How can i change my silverlight project to windows phone 8.1 project

Comment: It can't be directly converted to WinRT. You need to rework on your project for this. If you just want to use ProgressRing then use a nuget package otherwise for converting code check this link https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/12/17/bring-your-windows-phone-silverlight-apps-to-windows-runtime-xaml-prepare-for-universal-app-development-in-windows-10/